# Using R, how do I test a dataframe of phrases to see if it contains keywords

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. One containing search phrases like this

```
   search.phrases
1  the quick
2  brown fox jumps
3  over the lazy 
5  dog
6  why
7  nobody knows
   ...
```

and another containing keywords

```
   keywords
1  quick
2  lazy 
3  dog
4  knows
   ...
```

ideally, I want to find which search phrases contains one or more (either a boolean or a count) of the the keywords like this

```
   search.phrases      keyword.found     
1  the quick           TRUE
2  brown fox jumps     FALSE      
3  over the lazy       TRUE
5  dog                 TRUE
6  why                 FALSE
7  nobody knows         TRUE
   ...
```

I've been trying for a while now but I'm stumped. Any help is very much appreciated.

Lots of Love

G

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried. lots of love.

Comment: Hi James, I worked out that I can do it manually one keyword at a time using grepl and then tried to use some apply methods but I am still quite new to R so nothing came close. Sorry.

Comment: A lot of positive vibes in this post.  I like it

Comment: Hey Richard, you are young and talented, the world is your oyster. Go for it!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grepl()`

```
rgx <- paste(as.character(df2$keywords), collapse = "|")
df$keyword.found <- grepl(rgx, df$search.phrases)
```

**Result:**

```
   search.phrases keyword.found
1       the quick          TRUE
2 brown fox jumps         FALSE
3   over the lazy          TRUE
5             dog          TRUE
6             why         FALSE
7    nobody knows          TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(keywords = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("dog", 
"knows", "lazy", "quick"), class = "factor")), .Names = "keywords", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
df <- structure(list(search.phrases = structure(c(5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 
3L), .Label = c("brown fox jumps", "dog", "nobody knows", "over the lazy", 
"the quick", "why"), class = "factor")), .Names = "search.phrases", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c("the quick fox", "had a dog", "named bruce") -> phrases
c("quick", "bruce") -> keywords
library(stringr)
str_split(phrases, " ") -> phrase_list
sapply(phrase_list, function(x) any(ifelse(x %in% keywords, TRUE, FALSE))) -> z
```

Comment: Not only does this fix today's problem but you also inadvertently solved yesterdays too. Nice job. Thanks